# $[G:\cap H_i]\leq\Pi[H_i:H_{i+1}]$

Tags: group-theory

If $H_0=G$ and $H_{n+1}\subseteq H_n\subseteq G$ for $n\in \mathbb N$, then $[G:\cap H_i]\leq\Pi[H_i:H_{i+1}]$.

I used Poincare inequality, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have a question about the expressions $[H_i:H_{i - 1}]$ on the right-hand side.  It seems to me they should read $[H_i:H_{i + 1}]$, since the problem is formulated so that $H_{i + 1} \subset H_i$, but not *vice-versa*.

Comment: @1950RobertLewis, many thanks

Comment: According to your notation, the subgroups form a chain $H_n \subseteq H_{n-1} \subseteq \cdots H_2 \subseteq H_1 \subseteq G$, so their intersection is just the smallest subgroup in the chain. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @DerekHolt, I've seen this problem when I was undergraduate student, and i could not solve it.  It belongs to Scott's book. Page 21, problem 1.7.19.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I think we are not assuming that the chain is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption in the question is $G = H_0 \geq H_1 \geq H_2 \geq \ldots \geq H$, where $H = \cap_{i = 0}^\infty H_i$.

Now $[H_0 : H_1][H_1 : H_2] \cdots [H_k : H_{k+1}] = [H_0 : H_{k+1}] = [G : H_{k+1}]$, so $\prod [H_i:H_{i+1}]$ is the limit of $[G:H_k]$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Since $[G:H] = [G:H_k][H_k : H]$, we have $[G:H] \leq [G : H_k]$ for all $k$. Taking the limit $k \rightarrow \infty$ on this inequality gives the result.